# How to create a procedure to run through table and send an email in Oracle Apex?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently using Oracle Apex 4.2 and I need a way to have the program run through a table and send a email if it has not been sent yet. What is the best way to do this and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want something like this (I'm speculating about your table definition, the names of your columns, etc.)

```
FOR m IN (SELECT *
            FROM email_table
           WHERE sent_yet = 'N')
LOOP
  apex_mail.send( p_to => m.to,
                  p_from => <<your email address>>,
                  p_body => m.text_of_email,
                  p_subj => m.subject );
  UPDATE email_table
     SET sent_yet = 'N'
   WHERE primary_key = m.primary_key;
END LOOP;
```

The [`apex_mail.send` procedure documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI342) shows more options that you can pass in.  Note that if you're not already sending email in this environment using `apex_mail`, you probably want to have a separate job that actually sends the queued up emails.  For example, this will submit a job that sends queued up emails every minute.

```
DECLARE
  l_jobno pls_integer;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'begin apex_mail.push_queue( <<smtp server>>, <<port>> ); end;',
                   sysdate + interval '1' minute,
                   q'{sysdate + interval '1' minute}' );
  commit;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could us help explain to me the process of APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE, and the apex_mail.send? I am still new to this and there a few things that puzzle me.

Comment: @Eric - Can you be more specific?  If you've looked through the documentation I linked to and you've looked through my answer and you have a specific question, I'd be happy to take a shot at answering it.  At a high level, `send` puts an email in the mail queue and `push_queue` actually sends the emails that are in the queue.

Comment: thank you, I have figured out my issue. It seems that i needed to in put a code for the security to allow apex to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the issue. I need a line of code to allow apex to send emails through my application.

```
BEGIN
wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id; 

for rst in (
    select aud.LAN_ID, aud.ID, sent.TEMPLATE_TEXT, temp.TEMPLATE_NAME from EMAIL_Audit aud
    INNER JOIN EAMAIL_SENT sent
    ON aud.TEMP_TEXT_ID = sent.id
    INNER JOIN EMAIL_TEMP temp
    ON sent.PROCESS_ID = temp.id
    WHERE SENT_IND is null
    )
loop

APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
    p_to => 'someEmail@email.com',
    p_from => 'otherEmail@email.com',
    p_body => rst.TEMPLATE_TEXT,
    p_subj => rst.TEMPLATE_NAME );

END loop;

    APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE; 

END;​
```

Comment: If you're running this code from APEX, the `set_security_group_id` call shouldn't be needed.  That should only be needed if you're doing this outside of APEX.  If you're running outside of APEX, you may want to use `utl_mail` rather than `apex_mail`.